# Get the served pages response header

Tags: javascript, http, header, response

I would need to retrieve response header value from the served pages request.

So, let's say I open the console and go to the following url ->

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_header.asp

The first request in the network tab will be a GET request with a response code (304) to this URL.

I would need to get the response header parameter value from this URL. Would it be possible in JavaScript?

Played a bit around -

```
window.fetch(window.location.href).then((res) => console.log(res.headers.get('x-cache')))
```

This works, but is it possible to get the headers from the original request and not make a new request?

Answer (score -1):

In the `window.location` object you have some interesting params like:

```
host: "stackoverflow.com"
hostname: "stackoverflow.com"
href: "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44527522/get-the-server-pages-response-header"
origin: "https://stackoverflow.com"
pathname: "/questions/44527522/get-the-server-pages-response-header"
```

That way you can get the url.

To retrieve the referrer, use `document.referrer`.

To access the user-agent, use `navigator.userAgent`.

Comment: I would not need to retrieve the url details, but the actual header of the HTTP request response.

Comment: Then the only way to get the header and the response code is to make an ajax call and then look at the `request.status` object that holds the code.